# SQL for Ordering event data by comparing to two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort the data by the current month to compare it with two dates.

I also need to order data by the current month. This means, that if the event start date or event end date is in the current month, those events need to show at the top.

For example - in my `events` table.

| Event Name | event_start_date | event_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 2022-06-09 | 2022-06-11 |
| Event 2 | 2022-07-08 | 2022-07-30 |
| Event 3 | 2022-05-29 | 2022-06-15 |
| Event 4 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-16 |

If the current month is June (06) then I want to get data by this order--

1. Event 3
2. Event 1
3. Event 4
4. Event 2

at Event 3 start date is past month, but the end date is in the current month. So I want it in the first position.
I have tried this query

```
IF(MONTH(event_start_date) < MONTH(NOW()), MONTH(event_start_date) + 12, MONTH(event_start_date)), DAY(event_start_date)
```

So in my last query, I have compared only event_start_date, but which events start from the past month and end at the current month, I also need them at the top.

So how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: 'current month is May (06) ' - is confusing me..or does your company year start in december?

Comment: What about the order of other events?

Comment: 'if the current month is JUNE (06) ' -- I have updated the description.

Comment: To me it seems that you simply want to order the rows by start date. Would be nice if you could show us an example when that's not the case!

Comment: Suppose the current month is June. Yes, I was targetting the start date, that's why it was returned this way - Event 1, Event 4, Event 2. Event 3. which was correct according to my query. But my requirement is this way - Event 3, Event 1, Event 4, and Event 2. Event 3 is at the top because - Event 3's end date is in the current month. However, I manage to build a query I have shared in the Answer section.

Comment: Event 1, 3 and 4... they all end in June. So it is still confusing why a simple `order by start_date` isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following query is working for my case.

```
ORDER BY IF(
            
        MONTH(IF(MONTH(event_start_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_start_date, IF(MONTH(event_end_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_end_date, event_start_date))) < MONTH(NOW()), 
        MONTH(IF(MONTH(event_start_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_start_date, IF(MONTH(event_end_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_end_date, event_start_date))) + 12,
        MONTH(IF(MONTH(event_start_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_start_date, IF(MONTH(event_end_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_end_date, event_start_date))) 
    ), 
    DAY(IF(MONTH(event_start_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_start_date, IF(MONTH(event_end_date)=MONTH(NOW()), event_end_date, event_start_date)))
```

Thanks.